# mysql value became 0 (zero)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

any help please why mysql value became zero it have type double after it have value 0,50 in mysql it became 0.00

```
Sub absennaik()
    Dim u As Double
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
        inputabsen = Val(dgv.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
        If inputabsen <= absenbagus Then
            u = 0
        ElseIf inputabsen >= absenburuk Then
            u = 1
        Else
            u = (inputabsen - absenburuk) / (absenburuk - absenbagus)
        End If
        Dim cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("select * from fuzzy where fkode='" & i & "'", conn)
        Dim rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        rd.Read()
        If Not rd.HasRows Then
            Dim sqltambah As String = "insert into fuzzy(fkode,faktifbaik) values " & "( '" & i & "','" & u & "')"
            Dim cmd1 = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(sqltambah, conn)
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Else
            Dim sqledit As String = "Update fuzzy set " & "faktifbaik ='" & u & "' where fkode = '" & i & "'"
            Dim cmd1 = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(sqledit, conn)
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
    NextEnd Sub`
```

Comment: Not sure, but you are sending the value to the database as a string, which seems odd - is that to try and work around your language settings using a comma as a decimal separator?  I would guess that MySQL doesn't know how to parse '0,5' into a double, and comes up with 0 (perhaps stopping at the comma).  If that's the case, using a parameterized command would probably work (and be better in general), but formatting the double using a period as a separator may work too.

Comment: hellow mark yes you true i change in control panel region coma and its work.thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I don't know, this would have been far too big for a comment which is why I'm submitting it as an answer, although some of this might actually help.

Your question is weak, there isn't enough information for anyone to really identify enough information to help you.  Is it being set to zero because `inputabsen <= absenbagus` and causing the variable to become 0?

You meed to at a minimum write an actual question and provide information, database schema information, trace, debug statements etc anything that will actually help someone without a crystal ball answer it.

Some oservations, you're using MySQL and VB.NET, is there any reason why you're not using [the MySQL .NET provider](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) which is actually very good and specifically designed to intimately know MySQL rather than a generic ODBC provider.

I know you're only dealing with integers here but parameters rather than inline SQL is really important - please search Google for `SQL Injection Attack`

Have you stepped though your code with a debugger attached to find out if it's application logic rather than database logic causing the issue?

Check the generated SQL by running it directly against the database.

Is the datatype of the column you're updating defiantly a decimal and what is the precision?

Is it a culture problem (x.xx vs x,xx)?

I'm guessing your new at programming and I was trying to provide useful suggestions so you can help yourself further - I came to that conclusion by reading your source code, for example `"Update fuzzy set " & "faktifbaik ='" &` for example - this is a totally redundant string concatanation and not a mistake an experienced person would be making, I really haven't intended to offend you or be rude in any way, just provide clear advice on how to move forward and hopefully resolve the issue.

Comment: yes thanks for your comment..yes it about dot and coma i change it in control panel,region change the coma with the dot and its clear thanks for your suggestion i dont know how to update the profesional mysql any sugestion tutor??